# Restoring a dialog after screen rotation

Tags: android, dialog, screen-rotation

I am experiencing what is more of a minor problem than anything else trying to restore an error dialog box in an activity during screen rotation (portrait to landscape or vice-versa).  The dialog box does get rendered correctly when the error occurs, but upon screen rotation the dialog is not restored correctly.  Instead, the entire screen becomes dim, but nothing is visible.  Here is the relevant code:

```
private void showErrorDialog() {
    // assume hasErrorDialog is true at this point
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SomeActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = SomeActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_alert, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
    TextView msgText = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.alertMessageText);
    msgText.setText("something went wrong");
    Button okButton = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.alertOkButton);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
            hasErrorDialog = false;
        }
    });

    alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.someActivity);
    int width = rl.getWidth();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout((int) (0.9 * width), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}
```

When the above method is called *after* the activity has loaded, and an error has happened, the dialog loads and behaves exactly as it should.  So the above code is completely working when called under usual conditions.

However, I added logic which uses saved instance state to try to "remember" that in fact there should be an error dialog.  Upon rotation, I attempt to call the above method again after checking for this instance state:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);

    bundle.putBoolean("HASERRORDIALOG", hasErrorDialog);
}
```

Then in `onCreate()` I attempt to check for this state, and if present, call `showErrorDialog()` again:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.some_activity);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        hasErrorDialog = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("HASERRORDIALOG");

        if (hasErrorDialog) {
            // this does not load the dialog correctly
            showErrorDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the questions/answers I have read on Stack Overflow get around this problem by suggesting to use a `DialogFragment`.  While I'm open to going in this direction, I was wondering if there is not some remedy for my current code.

Comment: The `Activity` won't be laid out yet in `onCreate()`, so the width of that `RelativeLayout` is going to be 0.

Comment: @MikeM. I was suspecting this.  So perhaps I can persist this width in the instance state.  I will try this, and if it works you may post as an answer.

Comment: Or you could base that dimension on the screen metrics instead. Or defer showing the `Dialog`; e.g., by putting it in a `Runnable` that you `post()` on the `RelativeLayout`. Probably some other options I'm not thinking of atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running with the excellent comment by @MikeM, I realized the problem was that the `RelativeLayout` of my activity had not yet been fully created in the `onCreate()` method, and hence its width was not what I was expecting (likely to be zero).

As a workaround, I used `getDisplayMetrics()` to access the actual device width, which does still exist at the point in the lifecycle where `onCreate` gets called:

```
alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
int width = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*0.90);
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

The lesson to be learned here is that there is a potential caveat when basing a dialog off something in your layout.  In this case, when attempting to restore that dialog in `onCreate` after device rotation would fail, but this is one possible workaround.